# longest substring of non repeating characters javascript

Tags: javascript

The problems asks "given a string, find the longest non-repeating sub-string without repeating characters". I am a little stumped why returning my code is not working for the string "dvdf" for example. Here is my code :

```
function lengthOfLongestSubstring(check) {
    var letters = check.split("");
    var max = 0;
    var result = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < letters.length; i++) {
        var start = i
        if (result.indexOf(letters[i]) === -1) {
            result.push(letters[i])
        } else {
            i = i - 1
            result = []
        }
        if (max === 0 || max < result.length) {
            max = result.length
        }
    }
    return max
}
```

Comment: It returns `2` for me. Which I think is correct. Your implementation doesn't look correct though.

Comment: @Halcyon Longest sequence of unique characters in "dvdf" is "vdf" with length 3

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This implementation gives the correct result for `"dvdf"`.

It adds characters to `current_string` while there is no duplicate. When you find a duplicate cut `current_string` to the point of the duplicate. `max` is the max length `current_string` had at any time. This logic seems correct to me so I think it's correct.

```
function lengthOfLongestSubstring(string) {
    var max = 0, current_string = "", i, char, pos;

    for (i = 0; i < string.length; i += 1) {
        char = string.charAt(i);
        pos = current_string.indexOf(char);
        if (pos !== -1) {
            // cut "dv" to "v" when you see another "d"
            current_string = current_string.substr(pos + 1);
        }
        current_string += char;
        max = Math.max(max, current_string.length);
    }
    return max;
}

lengthOfLongestSubstring("dvdf"); // 3
```

The value of `current_string` in each round is `"", "d", "dv", "vd", "vdf"`.

Comment: Your solution is O(n^2). Can we solve this problem in O(n) ?

Comment: I don't think O(n) is possible. O(n log n) seems doable if you change the `indexOf` for a hash lookup. That seems purely theoretical though, I don't see how you would need extreme performance in a real life use case.

Comment: When you use `current_string.substr`, that is not an O(1) operation. Internally, that’s a loop of its own.

Comment: @OmShankar so is indexOf, but n+n = 2n is n

Comment: @EugenSunic, `indexOf` (and `substr`) is not **n+n**, it’s **n x m**

Answer (score 5):

By replacing the `result` array with a map storing the last index for each encountered character, you can modify the loop body to jump back to one after the last index of an identical character and continue your search from there instead of just restarting from the current position via currently `i = i - 1` which fails in cases such as `'dvdf'`:

Below is your code with changes to accommodate a map in place of an array:

```js
function lengthOfLongestSubstring(check) {
  var letters = check.split("");
  var max = 0;
  var result = new Map();
  var start = 0;
  
  for (var i = 0; i < letters.length; i++) {
    if (!result.has(letters[i])) {
      result.set(letters[i], i);
    } else {
      i = result.get(letters[i]);
      result.clear();
    }
    
    if (max < result.size) {
      max = result.size;
    }
  }
  return max;
}

// Example:
console.log(lengthOfLongestSubstring("dvdf")); // 3
```

Comment: Very nice use of map here!

Comment: how about if I had to return the max subsequence.. wonder if the time complexity changes then(I think it will).. because we would have to copy over the entries of the map to some placeholder for storage of that max subsequence right and then return it?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution using Sliding window and HashMap.

```
var lengthOfLongestSubstring = function(str) {
  if (!!!str.length || typeof str !== 'string') return 0;

  if (str.length == 1) return 1;
  let hashTable = {};
  let longestSubstringLength = 0;
  let start = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    if (hashTable[str[i]] !== undefined && hashTable[str[i]] >= start) {
      start = hashTable[str[i]] + 1;
    }
    hashTable[str[i]] = i;
    longestSubstringLength = Math.max(longestSubstringLength, (i - start + 1))
  }
  return longestSubstringLength;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I figured out an easier solution:

```js
function longestSubstring(str) {
    let left = 0;
    let max = 0;
    let result = new Set();

    for (let r = 0; r < str.length; r++) {
        //The code will check for an existing item on the set
        // If found, all the previously saved items will be deleted
        // the set will return to being empty
        while (result.has(str[r])) {
            result.delete(str[left]);
            left += 1;
        }
        result.add(str[r]);
        max = Math.max(max, r - left + 1);
    }

    console.log(result);
    return max;
}

console.log(longestSubstring('abcabccbc')); //3
```

Answer (score 1):

Today (January 7th, 2021) this was the Leetcode question of the day. I initially used a solution very similar to the selected answer. Performance was okay but after reviewing the answer solution documentation I rewrote my answer using the sliding window technique (examples were only in Java and Python) since I was curious about how much of a performance improvement this would result in. It is slightly more performant (144ms versus 160ms) and has a lower memory footprint (42mb versus 44.9mb):

```
function lengthOfLongestSubstring(s: string): number {
    let stringLength = s.length;
    let maxLength = 0;
    const charMap = new Map();
    let pos = 0;

    for (let i = 0; i < stringLength; i++) {
        if (charMap.has(s[i])) {
            pos = Math.max(charMap.get(s[i]), pos);
        }

        maxLength = Math.max(maxLength, i - pos + 1);
        charMap.set(s[i], i + 1);
    }
    return maxLength;
}

console.log(lengthOfLongestSubstring("dvdf"));
```

Comment: Hello how did you measure the performance ? any tool available ?

Comment: @James_RajKumar The metrics provided were from Leetcode's performance analysis tool when you submit an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function lengthOfLongestSubstring (str) {
  const map = new Map();
  let max = 0;
  let left = 0;
  for (let right = 0; right < str.length; right++) {
    const char = str[right];
    if (map.get(char) >= left) left = map.get(char) + 1;
    else max = Math.max(max, right - left + 1);
    map.set(char, right);
  }
  return max;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```js
function lengthOfLongestSubstring(str) {
    let longest = "";
    for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
        if (longest.includes(str[i])) {
            return longest.length
        } else {
            longest += str[i];
        }
    }
    return longest.length;
}

console.log(lengthOfLongestSubstring("abcabcbb"));
console.log(lengthOfLongestSubstring("bbbbb"));
console.log(lengthOfLongestSubstring("abcdef"));
console.log(lengthOfLongestSubstring(""));
```

Comment: this will failr for "pwwkew"

Answer (score 0):

reset i to i -1 is incorrect. you need another loop inside the for loop. you try something like this (i didn't check the index carefully).

```
function lengthOfLongestSubstring(check){
    var letters = check.split("");
    var max = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < letters.length; i++) {
        var result = [];
        var j = i;
        for(;j < letters.length; j++) {
            if (result.indexOf(letters[j]) === -1) {
                result.push(letters[j]);
            } else {
                break;
            }        
        }
        if(j - i > max) {
            max = j - i;
        }
    }
    return max;
}
```

Comment: Your implementation gives `dvdf=2`. I should be 3. I don't really understand why you need the 2nd loop.

Comment: @Halcyon there's an error in my original code. checking against max should be done outside of the second for loop, not within the loop. of course you don't need the second loop, but it's one way to find the longest substring.

Answer (score 0):

You can try **sliding window pattern** to solve this problem.

```js
function lengthOfLongestSubstring(str) {
  let longest = 0;
  let longestStr = "";
  let seen = {};
  let start = 0;
  let next = 0;

  while (next < str.length) {
    // Take current character from string
    let char = str[next];

    // If current character is already present in map
    if (seen[char]) {
      // Check if start index is greater than current character's last index
      start = Math.max(start, seen[char]);
    }

    // If new substring is longer than older
    if (longest < next - start + 1) {
      longest = next - start + 1;
      // Take slice of longer substring
      longestStr = str.slice(start, next + 1);
    }
    // Update current characters index
    seen[char] = next + 1;
    // Move to next character
    next++;
  }

  console.log(str, "->", longestStr, "->", longest);
  return longest;
}

lengthOfLongestSubstring("dvdfvev");
lengthOfLongestSubstring("hello");
lengthOfLongestSubstring("1212312344");
```

Answer (score 0):

Find Longest Unique Substring using Map Method

```
var str = "aaabcbdeaf";
var start = 0;
var map = new Map();
var maxLength = 0;
var longStr = '';

for(next =0; next< str.length ; next++){
if(map.has(str[next])){
  map.set(str[next],map.get(str[next])+1);
  start = Math.max(start,map.get(str[next]));
}
if(maxLength < next-start+1){
  maxLength = next-start+1;
  longStr = str.slice(start,next+1);
}
 map.set(str[next],next);
}
console.log(longStr);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like that:

```js
function maxSubstring(s) {
  const array = []
  const lengthS = s.length
  const pusher = (value) => {
    if (value !== '') {
      if (array.length > 0) {
        if (array.indexOf(value) === -1) {
          array.push(value)
        }
      } else {
        array.push(value)
      }
    }
  }
  pusher(s)
  for (const [index, value] of s.split('').entries()) {
    let length = lengthS
    let string = s
    const indexO = s.indexOf(value)
    pusher(value)
    while (length > indexO) {
      pusher(string.slice(index-1, length + 1))
      length = --length
    }
    string = s.slice(index, lengthS)
  }
  array.sort()
  return array.pop()
}

console.log(maxSubstring('banana'))
console.log(maxSubstring('fgjashore'))
console.log(maxSubstring('xyzabcd'))
```

Comment: Hope It will solve issue but please add explanation of your code with it so user will get perfect understanding which he/she really wants.

Comment: First of all, we create an array of substrings by going through each letter separately and deleting each time a character from the original string at each iteration, that is, in the given code, the entire array of substrings is collected in the for of loop. the pusher function checks if such a value is individual and it is not in the array then push it. after collecting everything under the lines, we sort this array and take the last element from it.

Answer (score 0):

Find Longest unique substring without using MAP(). Just simple slice().
***The same can be used to return longest unique string.***

*Just replace "return max => return str"*

```
const string = "dvdf";

var lengthOfLongestSubstring = function() {
if(string.length == 1) return 1;
if(string.length == 0) return 0;

let max = 0,i =  0, str = "";

while(i < string.length){
    const index = str.indexOf(string.charAt(i));
    if(index > -1) {
        // s = "fiterm".slice(1,4) => ite
        str = str.slice(index + 1, string.length);
    }
    str += string.charAt(i);
    max = Math.max(str.length, max);
    i++;
}
  return max;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

**Logest unqiue substring:**

```
function lengthOfLongestSubstring(s) {
    if(s.length < 2) {
        return s.length;
    }
    
    let longestLength = 1;
    let currentStr =  '';
    
    for(let i=0 ; i < s.length ; i++){
        if(currentStr.includes(s.charAt(i))){
           let firstSeen = currentStr.indexOf(s.charAt(i));
            currentStr = currentStr.substring(firstSeen+1,currentStr.length);   

        }
          currentStr += s.charAt(i);
          longestLength = Math.max(currentStr.length,longestLength);
    }
     
    return longestLength;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

One liner with reduce method.

```js
const subStrOfUniqueChar = str => [...str].reduce((p,c) => ( p.includes(c) ? (p += c, p.substr(p.indexOf(c)+1)) : p += c),'');
console.log(subStrOfUniqueChar('dvdf').length);
```

Comment: this will fail with `abbbcabcdefef`

Answer (score 0):

```
function lengthOfLongestSubstring(s: string): number {
  const arr = s.split("");
  let longest = 0;
  const set: Set<string> = new Set();
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    set.add(arr[i]);
    let tryIndex = i + 1;
    while (arr[tryIndex] && !set.has(arr[tryIndex])) {
      set.add(arr[tryIndex]);
      tryIndex++;
    }
    if (set.size > longest) {
      longest = set.size;
    }
    set.clear();
  }

  return longest;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to toss my hat in this ring because I feel like I've found a pretty creative solution to this. No if/else blocks are needed as the substring.indexOf() will attempt to find the matching string character in the array and delete the indexes of the array up to, and including, the match (+1). If an indexOf() call finds no match it will return a -1, which added to +1 becomes a .splice(0,0) which will remove nothing. The final Math check factors in the last character addition in the loop to determine which outcome is higher.

```
const findSubstring = string => {
let substring = [];
let maxCount = 0;
for (let i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
    maxCount = Math.max(substring.length, maxCount);
    substring.splice(0, substring.indexOf(string[i]) + 1);
    substring.push(string[i]);
}
maxCount = Math.max(substring.length, maxCount);
return maxCount;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> uses sliding window concept

```
function lengthOfLongestSubstring(s) {
  var letters = s.split("");
  var subStr = "";
  var result = [];
  var len = 0;
  let maxLen = 0;

  for (var i = 0; i < letters.length; i++) {
    const position = result.indexOf(letters[i]);
    if (position === -1) {
      result.push(letters[i]);
      len += 1;
    } else if (letters[i]) {
      result = result.splice(position + 1);
      len = result.length + 1;
      result.push(letters[i]);
    }
    maxLen = len > maxLen ? len : maxLen;
  }
  return maxLen;
}

console.log(lengthOfLongestSubstring(" "));
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

**Sliding Window Technique O(n)**

- you can use **hash** or **Map** in

1. loop through string char
2. Maintain dictionary of unique char
3. if char exist in memory take clear hash update the count in longest variable and clear count
4. start from first repeated char + 1 again.

```js
var lengthOfLongestSubstring = function(s) {
    if(s.length<2) return s.length;
    let longest = 0;
    let count=0;
    let hash={}
    for (let i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
       //If char exist in hash
        if(hash[s[i]]!=undefined){
            i=hash[s[i]];
            hash={}
            longest = Math.max(longest, count);
            count = 0;
        }else{
            hash[s[i]]=i
            count = count+1;
        }
        
    }
    return Math.max(longest, count);
};

console.log(lengthOfLongestSubstring("abcabcbb"))
console.log(lengthOfLongestSubstring("au"))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// ABCDDDEFGHIJJKLMNOPQ -> DEFGHI

const getSetOfLongestNonRepeatingCharacters = (str) => {
  let noRepeatedStrings = str;
  const pattern = /(\w+)\1+/g;
  const matches = [...str.matchAll(pattern)].map((p) => p[1]);
  if (matches.length > 0) {
    noRepeatedStrings = noRepeatedStrings.replace(pattern, '_');
    let strArray = noRepeatedStrings.split('_');
    let longestNonRepeatingCharacters = strArray.reduce((a, b) =>
      a.length > b.length ? a : b
    );
    for (let i = 0; i < matches.length; i++) {
      let long1 = `${matches[i]}${longestNonRepeatingCharacters}`;
      let long2 = `${longestNonRepeatingCharacters}${matches[i]}`;
      if (str.indexOf(long1) > -1) {
        return long1;
      } else if (str.indexOf(long2) > -1) {
        return long2;
      }
    }
    return '';
  }
  return '';
};
const runTest = (func, result) =>
  func == result ? 'test passed' : `test failed. expected results : ${result}`;

console.log(getSetOfLongestNonRepeatingCharacters('ABCDEF'));

console.log(
  runTest(
    getSetOfLongestNonRepeatingCharacters('ABXFGHIKCDDDEFGHI'),
    'ABXFGHIKCD'
  )
);
console.log(
  runTest(getSetOfLongestNonRepeatingCharacters('ABCDDDEFGH'), 'DEFGH')
);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information, such as explanation, citations or documentation. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

it is not working for "pwwkew" this string

```js
function lengthOfLongestSubstring(str) {
    let longest = "";
    for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
        if (longest.includes(str[i])) {
            return longest.length
        } else {
            longest += str[i];
        }
    }
    return longest.length;
}

console.log(lengthOfLongestSubstring("abcabcbb"));
console.log(lengthOfLongestSubstring("bbbbb"));
console.log(lengthOfLongestSubstring("abcdef"));
console.log(lengthOfLongestSubstring(""));
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34538592)